# How to get neurons weights from MultilayerPerceptronClassifier

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using a MLP Multiclass Classifier in pySpark (with Spark 1.6.0) following more or less the example from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/deep-learning-via-multilayer-perceptron-classifier).

Since I am interested in training the model once and then using the already-trained-model over different data sets, I would like to retrieve neurons weights (like it is explained [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/) for python sklearn using pickle package).

However, I am not being able to get the weights and internal parameters of the model after reading the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/MultilayerPerceptronClassifier).

If it helps, my code is:

```
# Importing PySpark libraries
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

#%% Codigo inicio

if __name__ == "__main__":

    conf  = SparkConf().setAppName("prueba_features")
    sc    = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    hc    = HiveContext(sc)
    sqlc  = SQLContext(sc)

    # Load training data
    data = sqlc.read.format("libsvm")\
        .load("/user/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt")

    # print data
    print("\nData set: \n{}".format(data))

    # Split the data into train and test
    splits = data.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4], 1234)
    train = splits[0]
    test = splits[1]

    # print sets
    print("\nTraining set: \n{}".format(train))
    print("\nTest set: \n{}".format(test))

    # specify layers for the neural network:
    # input layer of size 4 (features), two intermediate of size 5 and 4
    # and output of size 3 (classes)
    layers = [4, 5, 4, 3]

    # create the trainer and set its parameters
    trainer = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=100, layers=layers, blockSize=128, seed=1234)

    # train the model
    model = trainer.fit(train)

    # compute precision on the test set
    result = model.transform(test)
    predictionAndLabels = result.select("prediction", "label")
    evaluator_prec = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="precision")
    evaluator_rec = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="recall")
    evaluator_f1 = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="f1")

    # print fitting precision and results
    print("\nResults: \n{}".format(result))

    print("\nKPIs")
    print("Precision: " + str(evaluator_prec.evaluate(predictionAndLabels)))
    print("Recall: " + str(evaluator_rec.evaluate(predictionAndLabels)))
    print("F1-score: " + str(evaluator_f1.evaluate(predictionAndLabels)))

    # we end the SparkContext
    sc.stop()
```

Does anybody know how to do it if possible using pySpark MLP?

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is [`weights`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=weights#pyspark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.weights):

> `weights`
>
> the weights of layers.
>
> New in version 2.0.0.

As the annotation says, you'll need to update you Spark version to at least 2.0 to be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks! But upgrading to 2.0.0 is not an option since the environment cannot be modified... Isn't there an option in Spark 1.6.0 to initialize a MLP Classifier exactly as other one using a file with config parameters, for instance?